# Rest Assured & Spring - Value Becomes Null After First Test

Tags: java, spring, rest-assured

I have a strange problem. I've written my API and I just wanted to test it.

I wrote a simple test code by using `Restassured`:

```
package com.example.restservicetest;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;

import java.util.*;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class RestServiceTestApplicationTests {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private Response response;
    private List<Object> folderList;

    @Test
    public void getWholeFolders() {
        response = RestAssured.given().port(port).when().get("/api/opening").then().statusCode(200).extract().response();
        folderList= response.jsonPath().getList("folders");
    }

    @Test
    public void getRandomFolderNumber() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        RestAssured.given().port(port).when().get("/api/opening/folder/" + rand.nextInt(folderList.size()-1)).then().statusCode(200);
    }

}
```

When I debug my test, at the end of first `getWholeFolders` test, I see that `folderList` is not empty as I expected. My whole folder list is assigning to it.

But when the time is for 2nd test `getRandomFolderNumber`, I see that `folderList` becomes `null`.

Why does it become null?

Comment: Try writing unit tests that are not dependent on other unit tests or state or order. To solve your problem, you could use a `Before` or a constructor.

Comment: I believe that's because before each test the state is cleared. So that each test start from whatever is the initial state. As it is said in https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/junit-5-test-lifecycle/: "In JUnit, for each test – a new instance of test is created." So, I think, that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andriy mentiond in comment, JUnit Jupiter will use a default lifecycle mode, it means JUnit creates a new instance of each test class before executing each test method `TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD`.

To change that, you change `PER_METHOD` --> `PER_CLASS` (basically means one instance of test class for all test method).

One more subtle thing, you need to set order for test method to make sure `getRandomFolderNumber` always run after `getWholeFolders`

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class RestServiceTestApplicationTests {
    ...

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void getWholeFolders() {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    public void getRandomFolderNumber() {
        ...
    }

}
```